# PHP, Doxygen and raw HTML

Tags: php, html, doxygen, comments

I would like to include into the documentation some raw HTML. I am using Doxygen to generate this documentation so it is included in the PHP script.

The problem is that if I do this:

```
\\\ \htmlonly
<table>
.... etc

\\\ \endhtmlonly
```

PHP parses the raw HTML and hence produces errors.

But if I add '///' at the start of each line that occurs in the generated page.

What is the solution to this problem? Or is it possible to get Doxygen to generate a table using the various tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the context of your example code, since I do not know PHP, but generally doxygen comments look like:

```
/// \htmlonly
/// <table>
/// .... etc
/// \endhtmlonly
```

Notice how all *comment*  lines (doxygen parses comments, not source code to generate the documentation) start with `///`, even the HTML code. The `///` will be stripped from the HTML before being included in the documentation. Try the above and see if that fixes your problem. If not, can you provide some more context, i.e. a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that raw HTML is a bit unreadable in a text editor with all the tags. However I (nor this board for that matter) cannot think of a better solution. Perhaps a future enhancement to Doxygen.

Comment: However you get the "tick" as nobody else has answered.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use `include()`? That parses the HTML, but that is not needed. Use [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) instead.